# Android newbie: switch between landscape mode and portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I followed the android developrs [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) to create a simple tab layout. Everything is fine with the tutorial, I got the tab layout working.

In default **portrait** mode, the tabs are located on top of screen, but when change to landscape mode, the tabs on the top makes the screen looks odd, so, I would like to locate the tabs on the **left side** of the screen **vertically** when the emulator change to **landscape** mode.

I am not sure What is the correct way to do it? I mean the correct way to define different tabs layout for **portrait** mode and **landscape** mode. Anybody can give some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create two layout files one for portrait and one for landscape. place these layout-port and layout-land respectively. You'll have to handle screen orientation if u want to save the state of the screen

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up 2 different layouts for the activity, one in portrait ("normal") mode, one in landscape mode. This implies to not use TabActivity.

Put `landscape_tab.xml` in layout-land folder inside res folder (`res/layout-land`)

Put `portrait_tab.xml` in layout-port folder inside res folder (`res/layout-port`)

OfCourse you  have to create `layout-land` and `layout-port` folder in res directory manually

Your Solution is here 
[android:orientation="vertical" does not work for TabWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149953/androidorientation-vertical-does-not-work-for-tabwidget)

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

On your AndroidMainfest.xml add

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation" >
</activity>
```

And when application changes orientation, override the method on your `MyActivity.java`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            // do what you want
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            // do what the other thing you want
    }

}
```

This from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

Tip: When orientation changes, the Activity is restarted if you don't add `android:configChanges`.