# Android tabs vs. landscape orientation

Tags: android, orientation, landscape, android-tabhost, ui-design

I have a tab-based Android app. Currently, it does not support landscape mode - the one and only activity swallows all orientation changes. Now, a user asks that I support landscape for the sake of the hardware keyboard convenience.

On one hand, it makes sense. On the other, the default behavior of a tab host is rotating the tab strip; when it does, it takes a good one third of the precious screen space for the tabs alone. So I lose a lot of real estate.

Are there any common ways out of this conundrum? As far as as I can see, a vertical tab strip is not an option.

Comment: Worth mentioning [stackoverflow.com/q/4149953/42452](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4149953/42452) regarding no vertical tabs.

Comment: @cdhabecker: I ended up implementing this technique. Make it an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest following the technique discussed in [Timores's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4149953/42452) to [android:orientation="vertical" does not work for TabWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4149953), where he describes how to set up the TabHost to display the tabs on the left of the screen, with tabs vertically stacked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use tabs. That's probably the best suggestion anyone can give. Tabs on a mobile devices are a great way to display quick information, and a lot of information. But when it comes to handling user inputs, it doesn't really help considering that it's a mobile device with limited real estate.

Comment: OK, what alternative way of random-access multiple screen navigation can you think of?

Comment: I am not sure, May be you need to re-think about your UI now :) Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

While this has already been answered (and I like the one you accepted--will probably implement it myself), there is another option.

Use buttons instead of tabs to navigate between Activities.  Each Activity has the same series of buttons in the same locations, much like a navigation bar on web pages.

You can place your buttons however you like, depending on the orientation or however your design sees fit.

For examples, just look at any of the millions of websites with navbars, such at StackOverflow.com at the top of this page.