# How can I show a tab layout but in a vertical view?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, paging

I am trying to implement a vertical tab layout. I have tried to set the orientation of the TabLayout to vertical but no luck.

I want the user to swipe vertically instead of horizontally

Comment: You can refer to this question this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422626/vertical-android-tablayout-not-scroll-vertically/41422781

Comment: I saw this question, it is the same as mine but I want the tabs instead of being on the left I want it on the top

Comment: It's pretty clear from developer's site that TabLayout is meant for horizontal only.. If you want to achieve something similar in vertical, i think you might want to use a third party library, implement a custom view extending the tabLayout or create similar using recyclerView/ListView options..