# Vertical tabLayout on Android (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android-studio, xamarin

**Issue**

Make a vertical tablayout but it uses more spaces than it need.
In addition, I want tabItem's text be horizonal.

I couldn't paste an image so I paste a link that I asked at other website.
She told me that make a vertical tab with tablayout is impossible.

**Screen I want to make**

First image is the display what I want to make. Second image is the display at now.

https://teratail.com/questions/0p99tlvnpzqpoj

**Code**

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--AppBar
        @+id/appBar-->
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:expanded="false">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="46dp">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <!--Tab & Content-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLay_TabContent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linLay_EventRep"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBar">
        
        <!--Tab & image
        @+id/Tab-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Tab"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:rotation="-90"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabLayoutTextAppearance"
                app:tabMinWidth="79dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:text="test1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:text="test2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:text="test3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="19dp"
                android:paddingLeft="17dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
            
        <!--Content
        @+id/Content-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Tab">
            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/txt1"
              android:text="data"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linLay_EventRep"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/txt1"
              android:text="text1"
              android:layout_width="78dp"
              android:layout_height="48dp"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/txt2"
              android:text="text2"
              android:layout_width="78dp"
              android:layout_height="48dp"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
        </LinearLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Version**

Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.19

Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.04084

MonoAndroid, Version=v9.0

**remarks**
I checked this site but couldn't understand the meaning of code **Setup in Code** thus couldn't write with C#.

[Vertical Android TabLayout not scroll vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422626/vertical-android-tablayout-not-scroll-vertically)

Comment: This question is not related to Kotlin or Java, please remove those tags.

Comment: could you simplify the code you provide so that I can reproduce the situation you described.

Comment: sorry for reply late. I fixed tags and code. I think you can check code with no error. If there are any problems please tell me. I will check as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test the code you provided and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422626/vertical-android-tablayout-not-scroll-vertically) provided. Unfortunately, TabLayout can't achieve the effect you want. And here is my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie4i4.jpg) of test effect. As the second answer in the link said:

> TabLayout provides a horizontal layout to display tabs.

You can choose this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267951/vertical-tabs-in-android/7268225#7268225)'s method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I wonder that why  [respondent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41422626/vertical-android-tablayout-not-scroll-vertically) could make a vertical Tab by code. And I couldn't understand the meaning of the code...

Comment: @yukiyuki Sorry about that. This is a new question, and you should make a new post to ask :) And please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ✅ as an answer if it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks in advance!