# How to display Tab bar on the left of the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android and I have just started working on application for the first time.
I have created/using a tab bar view to display multiple view.

I am getting the `tab bar` at the bottom of the screen.
However I want to display the tab bar on the left of the screen.

The code I am using is as follows.

```
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

My `activity_main.xml` is as follows:-

```
  <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#2184C6" />
```

The image i am getting is:-
[image]

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Set a fixed width for the TabBar and use android:layout_alignParentLeft="true".

Comment: @Demonick I have tried it but it is not helping..

Comment: use action bar sherlock tabs

Comment: See this for native implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149953/androidorientation-vertical-does-not-work-for-tabwidget