# how to change the layout in frame layout on the click event?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

i have an layout consisting of two frame layout, my first Frame layout consist of the buttons,and another Frame layout is blank ,on click event on the button in first frame layout i wish to load the Activity layout in the second Frame layout?
This is my XML LAYOUT

```
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mainframelayout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/mainliner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#565765">
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/leftlayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="#321324">
            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/liner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="firstButton"
                android:text="A"/>
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="fifthButton"
                android:text="B"/>
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="secondButton"
                android:text="C"/>
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="thirdButton"           
                android:text="D"/>          
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="fourthButton"
                android:text="E"/>
            </LinearLayout>                 
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/rightframe"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#565765">

        </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Layoyt.setvisable(visiable)

Comment: post your xml layout code

Comment: From my buttons in framelayout with id-"@+id/leftlayout", i wish to update my framelayout with id-"@+id/rightframe".

Comment: Thanks @Naveen Tamrakar...!!
Your Option did worked out for me...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This was the  Finalized Solution to my problem.
On the click event of my button i Just have to set the Visibility of the Desired framelayout to be visible.

/////////////////////////// The XML LAYOUT//////////////////////////////////////////


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mainliner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relative"
        android:background="#454565">
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/leftlayout"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/liner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#FF9B00"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="firstButton"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbtn"
            android:text="A"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="secondButton"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbtn"
            android:text="B"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="thirdButton"          
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbtn"
            android:padding="1dp" 
            android:text="C"/>          
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbtn"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:onClick="fourthButton"
            android:text="D"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:onClick="fifthButton"
            android:text="E"/>
        </LinearLayout>                 
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rightframeone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#123139"
        android:visibility="invisible">
       <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:columnWidth="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView> 
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rightframetwo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#121232"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/aaaimage"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rightframethree"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#454425"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imagevieww"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/bstclass"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rightframefour"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#567004"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imageviewww"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/bstteam"
            />      
    </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/rightframefive"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#324888"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imageviewwww"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/training"
            />      
    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


//////////////////The Method to the triggered in the Class on the click event////////////////////

This the functionality we need to do on our button

    public void firstButton(View view) 
    {
        frmtwo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        frmtwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        frmthree.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        frmthree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        frmfour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        frmfour.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        frmfiv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        frmfiv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        frmone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to use fragment for that.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction();
CalculatorTwo calculator = new CalculatorTwo();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_top,
                        R.anim.slide_down);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_first, calculator);
ragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: use on your onclick event of button

Comment: try the above code in OnClick event of the button class must be fragment